# События типа: wheelup, wheeldown

Tags: javascript, ui

Необходимо отслеживать прокрутку колесика мыши: вверх или вниз. При этом сам элемент не скроллится. Как это можно реализовать? Нашел один интересный [вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/r05emt4r/), но он работает только в случае с прокруткой элемента:

```js
document.querySelector('.carousel').addEventListener('scroll', function(ev) {
    console.log("scroll event");
    const el = ev.target;
    const direction = el.scrollTop() > (el.data('scrollTop') || 0) ? "down" : "up";
    el.data('scrollTop', el.scrollTop());
    console.log('scrolling', direction);
}, { capture: true });
```

```css
.carousel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">carousel</div>
```

Под прокруткой элемента подразумевается возможность проскроллить его содержание.

Я понимаю, что события отслеживаются по взаимодействию с документом, поэтому задача кажется невыполнимой. Буду рад любому костылю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю это то что вам нужно.

```js
document.addEventListener("wheel",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.deltaY < 0) console.log("wheelUp");
    else console.log("wheelDown");
},{passive: false})
```

Дальше сами :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY);
  this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
})

//для того чтобы можно было поскролить
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  document.write('<div>scroll</div>')
}
```

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли суть моего вопроса. Мой элемент не должен скроллится, на нем лишь должны обрабатываться события.

Comment: но если событие не произойдет, то как его можно отследить? не понимаю зачем это, но возможно я неправиильно понял. Я же на виндов обработчик повесил, если скролить страницу, будут происходить события, по которым срабатывает функция и выводит направление скрола, но если на странице нет скрола, то это событие не произойдет

Comment: Собственно, поэтому я и задаю вопрос. Допустим, есть вертикальная карусель и мне нужно при событии колесика перемещаться по слайдам в соответствующем направлении. Возможно, я не правильно понял принцип написания таких UI.

Comment: ну это уже совсем другой вопрос, вот есть плагин https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/mousewheel.html